# Using tornado.auth.TwitterMixin with a callback URL?

Tags: python, twitter, tornado

I am trying to use tornado.auth.TwitterMixin with a callback url, but 
I am having problems with it. 
I am not sure how do i set the callback url from within the Tornado 
Application. 
Here's my class for tornado.auth.TwitterMixin :

```
class TAuthBindingHandler(BaseHandler,tornado.auth.TwitterMixin): 
    @tornado.web.asynchronous 
    def get(self): 
        if self.get_argument("oauth_token", None): 
self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth)) 
            return 
        self.authorize_redirect() 
    def _on_auth(self, user): 
        if not user: 
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Twitter auth failed") 
        tuser = self.db.get("SELECT * FROM twitterusers WHERE tid = 
%s",user["id"]) 
        bigU = self.get_current_user() 
        bigU_id = bigU['id'] 
        if not tuser: 
            any_tuser = self.db.get("SELECT * FROM twitterusers LIMIT 
1") 
            if not any_tuser: 
                tuser_id = self.db.execute( 
                    "INSERT INTO twitterusers (name,tid,user_id) 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", 
                    user["name"], user["id"], bigU_id) 
            else: 
                self.redirect("/") 
                return 
        else: 
            pass 
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))
```

My question is, where do i set the callback url ? How do i set it in 
this class?

I'm using Tornado 1.1 and I do not have any callbacks set in my twitter app settings.

I'm testing it out on localhost.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I'm not sure if you still need the answer, but `self.authorize_redirect` takes a `callback_uri`.  So in your case, I would write `self.authorize_redirect('http://localhost:8888/authentication-complete')`.  It took me a while to figure it out.  Good luck!